# File not found error in ME2

Tags: mass-effect-2

I was playing ME2 fine till last night. This morning I received a strange error as shown below. Before it was about new7_en.jpg. I have not changed any settings etc betweem last night and tonight.

Once I click on OK it goes away. Still if someone could provide a resolution would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Normally this kind of error only comes up with 16 bit applications (caused by a space in the filename) - never seen it with a game launcher for a modern game...

Comment: is this the steam or the origin version?  If its on steam, try verifying the integrity of your steam cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the missing files are just BMPs (most likely textures), you can probably silence this error by making some dummy images in Paint and saving them in the locations specified by the error messages.

Judging by the path names, I'm guessing these are for the news feed in the main menu, so replacing them by dummies probably won't make any noticeable gameplay difference.